# iOS uipickerview 2nd component shows results from previous selection

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am trying to make UIPickerView that allows you to choose a mobile phone.
It has two components you choose the brand first and then the phone.
it works perfectly but there is one issue when you choose a brand that has very few mobiles like one or two, the UIpickerView 2nd component shows some mobiles from the previous brand(if it has more mobiles) even if you cant choose them.

here is the brand that has more mobiles

[image: here is the brand that has more mobiles]

and this what happens when you choose after that a brand that has one phone

[image]

and here is the code

```
var brands : [Brand] = []{
        didSet
        {
            self.pick.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }
```

didselectrow function

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            if component == 1 {
                self.spinin.startAnimating()
                loadMobiles(brand_id: String(brands[row].id))
            } else{
                id1 = mobiles[row].id
                print(id1)
            }
 }
```

and load mobiles function

```
func loadMobiles(brand_id: String)
    {
        let url = URL(string: "http://myapi.com?id=\(brand_id)")!
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do{
                self.mobiles = try parse(data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.pick.reloadAllComponents()
                    self.pick.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
                    self.spinin.stopAnimating()
                }
            }
            catch{
                print("JSONParsing Error :\(error)")
            }

  }
        task.resume()
          }
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Show your titleForRow func

Comment: func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            if component == 1 {
                return brands[row].name
            } else{
                return mobiles[row].name
            }
    }

Comment: In my case, its working perfect. Check components once again.